# Call a class method from within that class

Tags: objective-c, class-method

Is there a way to call a class method from another method within the same class?

For example:

```
+classMethodA{
}

+classMethodB{
    //I would like to call classMethodA here
}
```

Comment: Firstly we say how to send message to method? Not how call a method? This is a way of saying it in obj-c.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: @Craftero don't you mean send a message to an object? Messages aren't sent to methods.

Comment: Oops my bad, Sorry! @inspectorg is right! it's send message to object

Answer (score 65):

In a class method, `self` refers to the class being messaged. So from within another class method (say classMethodB), use:

```
+ (void)classMethodB
{
    // ...
    [self classMethodA];
    // ...
}
```

From within an instance method (say instanceMethodB), use:

```
- (void)instanceMethodB
{
    // ...
    [[self class] classMethodA];
    // ...
}
```

Note that neither presumes which class you are messaging. The actual class may be a subclass.

Comment: You switched up your terminology. `[self foo]` for instance methods, `[MyClass bar]` for class methods.

Comment: Nope. The meaning of `self` depends on what you're messaging. If you message a class, `self` is the class. If you message an instance, `self` is the instance. I explain the importance of messaging self for class methods in http://qualitycoding.org/factory-method/

Comment: Agreed, what you're saying in your comment is true, but the terminology in your answer is literally backwards. Using `[self class]` in an instance method doesn't make much sense, but it makes complete sense in a class method. Remember that instance methods begin with `-`, class methods begin with `+`, and using `self` to refer to an instance of an object has syntactic meaning but using `[self class]` to refer to an instance of an object makes no sense syntactically. `[self class]` implicates reference to an object that describes the class, and not an instance of the class.

Comment: @inspectorg, I guess I'm not understanding you. Our context is the question, how to invoke a class method. If you want to invoke a class method from an instance method (my second example), I first invoke `[self class]` to get the object's actual class, which may or may not be `MyClass`.

Comment: I see what you're saying now, but the wording of your answer makes it unclear so you may want to edit it. You're saying that e.g. *inside* `classMethodB` of `MyClass` you want to call `classMethodA` of `MyClass`, you use `[self classMethodA]`; however, *inside* `instanceMethodB` of `MyClass` you want to call `classMethodA` of `MyClass`, you use `[[self class] classMethodA]`. This is correct! Your wording and simple examples suggests that one should use `self` to call class methods and `[self class]` to call instance methods, the latter of which is wrong (and what I thought you were saying).

Comment: +1 Yep, totally unambiguous now, thanks :) Now if only your answer was accepted, but unfortunately this question is over 6 months old...

Answer (score 8):

Should be as simple as:

```
[MyClass classMethodA];
```

If that's not working, make sure you have the method signature defined in the class's interface.  (Usually in a .h file)

Comment: That is one way to do it; however, that will not respect sub-classing.  In most cases it's probably wiser to use [self classMethodA].  As I understand in a class method "self" would be the class object (because class methods are instance methods of a class).  So MyClass's method would be called but not MyClassSubclass's classMethodA

Comment: Also note that he said in the question "within the same class"

Answer (score 4):

In objective C 'self' is used to call other methods within the same class.

So you just need to write

```
+classMethodB{
    [self classMethodA];
}
```

Comment: `self` is only proper for instance methods, but the question suggests he is talking about class methods (with the `+` sign before the method name)

Answer (score 3):

Sure.

Say you have these methods defined:

```
@interface MDPerson : NSObject {
    NSString *firstName;
    NSString *lastName;

}

+ (id)person;
+ (id)personWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirst lastName:(NSString *)aLast;
- (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirst lastName:(NSString *)aLast;


@property (copy) NSString *firstName;
@property (copy) NSString *lastName;

@end
```

The first 2 class methods could be implemented as follows:

```
+ (id)person {
   return [[self class] personWithFirstName:@"John" lastName:@"Doe"];
}

+ (id)personWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirst lastName:(NSString *)aLast {
    return [[[[self class] alloc] initWithFirstName:aFirst lastName:aLast]
                                                      autorelease];
}
```