# Calling class method from instance method in objective c

Tags: objective-c

What is the safe and correct way of calling a class method from an instance method in objective - C ?

Answer (score 2):

you can do like:

```
- (void)your_instanceMethodB
{

    [[self class] your_classMethodA];

}
```

READ this:  [**Call a class method from within that class**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290156/call-a-class-method-from-within-that-class?answertab=active#tab-top) 
            . Jon Reid and others answers.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer . So should i remove the question as a duplicate ?

Comment: @eddardstark : your should [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) ..I think you can flag for deletion but can't delete your self.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using subclasses and your subclass overrides the method, then you should do

```
 [[self class] myFunction];
```

If not, the standard way is correct

```
[MyClass myFunction];
```

Comment: Which one is the best practice ? Are there any other issues i need to be aware of (other than inheritance) ?

Comment: There are no issues, both ways are correct, the first is just used when you have subclasses